# How to add Continue Shopping button in checkout page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, html

We are trying to add *"Continue Shopping"* button after "Next" button in checkout page Magento 2.
We found that below file is the .html rendering the content.

```
\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\shipping.html
```

Can any one help me on how to add "*Continue Shopping*" after next button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i have done this by overriding files into my theme as i added below , hope this helps for someone.

app\design\frontend[Vendor][theme]\Magento_Checkout\web\template\shipping.html

```
      <div class="primary">
          <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
              <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Next'--><!-- /ko --></span>
           </button>
           </br>
           <a class="continue_shopping_url" data-bind = "attr: { href: continueShoppingUrl}">Continue Shopping</a>
      </div>
```

app\design\frontend[Vendor][theme]\Magento_Checkout\web\js\view\shipping.js

```
    initialize: function () {
    // inside this initialize function i called my bindings. 
    this.continueShoppingUrl = ko.observable(window.location.origin);
```

Comment: please update the detailed code of second step..i am new to this

Answer (score 0):

```
You can add Continue Shopping Link in file

/var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml
```

by placing this file in your theme.

```
You can add link either using php or by Jquery.I have play lot of more in this file by adding some links and for customize checkout page.
```

Hope it will help you.